# BatchNormalization for some inputs only in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm, batch-normalization

I have LSTM network that has 5 input. The 1st input typical values are from 1000 to 3000. Rest of inputs have values from -1 to 1.

I'd like to insert BatchNormalization as the 1st layer. But inputs 2-5 are already between -1 and 1 and the 1st input is much greater than the 1st input. That's I'd like to apply batch normalization for the 1st input only and leave inputs 2-5 as is. Then 1st (normalized) input and  2-5 inputs should be passed to LSTM layer.

```
      +----+   +---+
 1 -->| BN |-->|   |
      +----+   | L |
 2 ----------->| S |
 3 ----------->| T |
 4 ----------->| M | 
 5 ----------->|   |
               +---+
```

How can it be done in Keras?

I think that I can create the model with BatchNormalization bare layer for the 1st input and then concatenate it with rest of layers. But I'm not sure and don't know how exactly do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following definition:

```
from keras.layers.merge import concatenate

input_tensor = Input(shape=(timesteps, 5)) 

# now let's split tensors
split_1 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, :1])(input_tensor)
split_2 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, 1:])(input_tensor)

split_1 = BatchNormalization()(split_1)

# now let's concatenate them again
follow = concatenate([split_1, split_2])
```

But as Daniel mentioned in his comment - it's better to normalize data in order to deal with such inconsistencies - using `BatchNormalization` might result in worse performance.

Answer (score 2):

Considering you have training data shaped as `(batch,timeSteps,5)`, maybe you should simply change your input like this:

```
maxVal = abs(X_train[:,:,0].max())
minVal = abs(X_train[:,:,0].min())
maxVal = max(maxVal,minVal)

X_train[:,:,0] = X_train[:,:,0] / maxVal
```

Comment: Yes, I can. I even can apply normalization manually for the all timesteps before feeding to NN:

input_0 = X_train[:, :, 0]
X_train[:, :, 0] = (input_0 - input_0.mean()) / (math.sqrt(input_0.std()) - 0.001)**2

But I'd like to do this not only for 1 sample but for whole batch. And delegate it to Keras.

Comment: But there are thousands of input samples. And Keras will choose (for example) random 64 samples for the specific batch. If I understand Batch Normalization correctly, it's applied every time for every batch of 64 samples. Not to whole input set. If I have the sequence [0,0,0,1000,1000,1000] and timesteps=3 / batch_size=1, then without shuffle BN feeds 2 similar batches: [0,0,0]. But when BN is applied to every batch separately it'll be: [-1, -1, -1] and [1, 1, 1]

Comment: Not sure I understand how you're treating your inputs.... they should be of shape `(batch, steps, features)`.

Comment: I just simplified it for explanation. [0,0,0,1000,1000,1000] is one feature with 6 timesteps. So, for input shape (2, 3, 1) it'll be: [[0,0,0], [1000,1000,1000]]. So, Keras BN will normalize [0,0,0] and [1000,1000,1000] separately. But the code above normalizes whole sequence [0,0,0,1000,1000,1000]

Comment: Ok.... I thought normalizing the whole data would be better (after all, if all the data is of the same nature, it seems better to keep them inside a logical proportion), but if you do want separate normalizations, then let think of a way of fixing my answer...

Comment: This is a really poor answer Daniel. First of all - `BatchNormalization` doesn't subtract divide by `max` - but it reduces data using standard normalization. Second thing - is that it wouldn't work well during test time - at this will still normalize data based on data stats. Third - you take min and max and then again max out of these two numbers - this is pointless as max is no less than min in your code.

Comment: `abs` in both cases